# implementing AdMob to IOS using Cordova 2.2.0

Tags: ios, cordova, admob

I'm new to IOS app using Cordova, I'm Trying to implement AdMob to IOS application using Cordova 2.2.0 & Xcode 4.5.2

I've followed the documentation from AdMob, but I got 14 error, then I found this [link](http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2012/05/cordova-phonegap-and-admob-together-ios.html)
I followed all the mention steps, now I got a problem with :

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIDispatcher in:
    /Path to Project/Test/Add-ons/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta3/Library/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDispatcher.o)
    /Path to Project/Test/Add-ons/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta3/Library/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDispatcher.o)
ld: 214 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`

what is the meaning of this error ?
Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: try setting the other linker flags in the build settings of your project to `all_load`

Comment: I've already have it! not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest version of AdMob you only need the `-ObjC` linker flag, you should remove the `-all_load` linker flag.

Also make sure that you remove anything from the "`Add-ons`" directory that you aren't using. Specifically it looks like you're also including the Analytics library which you could remove (unless you're using in which case you probably don't need to include both the non-debug and debug version)